# I have an array of strings; is there a way to see which one an argument string is closest to?

Tags: python, compare, speech-recognition, phrase

I'm working in Python, and I've decided to break down and make a huge array of phrases for the result of a speech recognition module to compare to. So far I've got:

```
phrases = [
    "what time is it",
    "what's the weather",
    "what's the date",
    "hello",
    "hi",
    "what's up",
    "how are you"
]
```

(I've only just started this a few minutes ago, so I haven't got much yet... Mostly just an outline) But anyway, I'd like a function kind of like this...

```
def match(phrase):
    #match_greatest will start at zero but continuously update if the string
    #being compared has a higher percentage match
    match_greatest = 0

    #match will store the actual string that is closest
    match = ""

    for i in phrases:
        #this is the part I need help with...
        match_current = #somehow get the percentage that the argument phrase matches the phrase it's comparing to

        #if the current phrase is a closer match than before, update it
        if match_current > match_greatest:
            match_greatest = match_current
            match = i

    return match
```

...so as an example, if I call match("what time it a") or match("what time sit") -- these are examples of a misreading that the speech recognition could give -- and use my current set of phrases, it would return "what time is it".

Comment: Iterate over each character, if the character is the same at both locations, meaning in the string entered and string being matched, increment some variable and divide that variable at the end by the total length to the string you want to match. In other words create a percentage match

Comment: What are you using for mic-input?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasonable distances between strings is "edit distance" or [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance. It calculates amount of edits (insertions, deletions and substitutions) to turn one string into another.

Python implementation is here, it requires dynamic programming

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

You can also implement the algorithm yourself, it is pretty simple.

If you want speech-oriented distance it is worth to consider [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex), a specific extension of Levenshtein to account for phonetic properties of words. See

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy

You can iterate over strings and find which has smallest edit distance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how I would do it.

```
def match(phrase):
    phrases = [
    "what time is it",
    "what's the weather",
    "what's the date",
    "hello",
    "hi",
    "what's up",
    "how are you"
]


    match_word_dict = {}
    for element in phrases:
        sameness = 0
        for index in range(len(element)):
            if len(phrase) == index:
                break
            if phrase[index] == element[index]:
                sameness += 1



        percent = (sameness * 1.0 / len(element) * 1.0) * 100
        match_word_dict[element] = percent
    return match_word_dict

print match("hello")
print match("hel")
```

Where I return a dictionary that shows the phrase and percent match
Also here's how I would go about only printing the phrase with the highest percent match

```
key, value = max(match("hello").iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
print key, value
```

Comment: As it grows in complexity you can write a method that returns matches above some percent match.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an attempt. We can include many possibilities and other test cases which would lead to more complex logic than what I did below.

```
phrases = {
    1: "what time is it",
    2: "what's the weather",
    3: "what's the date",
    4: "hello",
    5: "hi",
    6: "what's up",
    7: "how are you"
    }


def match(phrase):
    """
    """
    phr_list = phrase.split()
    max_count = 0
    key = None

    for k, v in phrases.iteritems():
        count = sum(1 for word in phr_list if word.lower() in v.split())

        if count > max_count:
            count = max_count
            key = k

    if key:
        return phrases.get(key)
    return phrase


print match("what time it a")

print match("what time sit")    

print match(" how you good")
```

Yeilds:

```
what time is it
what time is it
how are you
```